# Find the lowest quadratic root in a specific interval

Tags: java, algorithm, quadratic

I want to create a Java method which returns the lowest root of a quadratic equation in the interval `(0, 1)`. If there are no solutions in the interval, return `1`. I need some help making this an efficient algorithm.

This is my current method:

```
public static float getLowestRoot(float A, float B, float C) {
    float D = B*B - 4*A*C;
    if(D < 0) return 1;

    float sD = (float) Math.sqrt(D);

    float x1 = (-B + sD) / (2*A);
    float x2 = (-B - sD) / (2*A);

    if(x2 < x1) {
        float tmp = x2;
        x2 = x1;
        x1 = tmp;
    }

    if(x1 > 0 && x1 < 1) return x1;
    if(x2 > 0 && x2 < 1) return x2;

    return 1;
}
```

This method does the job but I was wondering if there is a way to compress the algorithm, because right now it feels bloated.

Comment: What if the solution is 1?

Comment: I suggest switching the `float` with `double`. You will get more precise results.

Comment: I think that there's nothing fundamentally wrong with your code (except that I would *definitely* not use 1.0 to indicate "no solution" since it's also a valid solution).

Comment: @arynaq: then the return value should be 1.

Comment: @kocko: thanks for the suggestion but I don't need precision, floats are fine.

Comment: "If it's not broke don't fix it." Why do you think it's 'bloated'? Looks short and clean to me.

Comment: @NPE: In this application, I want 1.0 to be the return value if there are no solutions. But let's say I don't, what would be the return value in case of no solutions? It has to be a float right?

Comment: @Wilco: NaN sounds like a good candidate. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: @Troubleshoot: In this case I am searching for a method with maximum performance. The stated problem is really simple, and it feels like I am missing something which could easily reduce the algorithm into less lines of code.

Comment: If you know where the max / min is, then you may check the values of y(0) and y(1) first, since you might be able to skip rooting then, if all points have the same sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** note that "less lines of code" isn't the same as "better performance".

**2)** you can consider `Math.abs(sD) < Epsilon` - if yes, then you don't have to calculate both roots. I'm *guessing* that this can improve speed in such cases.

**3)** I think you can improve checking which root is smaller:

```
x1 <= x2 <===>  -B+sD/(2A) <= -B-sD/(2A) <==(adding sD/(2A) to both sides)==> 
         <===> -B+2sD/(2A) <= -B/(2A)    <==(adding B/(2A) to both sides)==>
         <===>    2sD/(2A) <= 0
         <===>           A <= 0 (because sD >= 0)
```

So you can avoid swapping the roots:

```
int signA = Math.signum(A);
float x1 = (-B + -signA * sD) / (2*A);
float x2 = (-B + signA * sD) / (2*A);

// always x1 <= x2
```

Again, I'm *guessing* that this improves performance, but I didn't measure it.

So, the final answer would look something like this:

```
public static float getLowestRoot(float A, float B, float C) {
    float D = B*B - 4*A*C;

    if (D < 0) return 1;

    if (Math.abs(D) < 0.0001)  // not sure how many 0s for float
    {
        float x = -B / (2*A);

        if (x > 0 && x < 1) return x;

        return 1;
    }

    float sD = (float) Math.sqrt(D);

    int signA = Math.signum(A);
    float x1 = (-B + -signA * sD) / (2*A);
    float x2 = (-B + signA * sD) / (2*A);

    if (x1 > 0 && x1 < 1) return x1;
    if (x2 > 0 && x2 < 1) return x2;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @Wilco I've changed the answer to show some performance ideas.